# How to open :Explore for a directory under the cursor?

Tags: open

I wonder how to open a file from a directory under the cursor.

I have managed to do it for simple directories, but it requires they are one single word and are located in the current working directory: In commandline mode, with `:e` and then `<ctrl+r>` `<ctrl+w>` for pasting the word under cursor, and then using tab for example for autocompletion, or `<Enter>` for opening the :Explore view of it.

However I have no idea for more complex directories.

Is there a solution ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "complex directories", but `<c-r><c-a>` will expand the WORD (where `<c-r><c-w>` expands a 'word'). Also, `gf` will open netrw if the file under the cursor is a directory. Of course, that only works if the file is in the `path` (`:h path`).

Comment: Both of your suggestions answer my point. `<c-r><c-a>` is great. And `gf` is just exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Biggybi mentions `gf` in the comments, and it is usually the best way to go. It takes you to the file (in your `path`) under the cursor. This should work for directories, too.

Alternately, you could use `:edit <cfile>` or alternatives, as explained [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3369/10604). (I believe also `:edit <C-r><C-f>`.)

Comment: Sorry, I saw your answer once I posted mine... <cfile> is so good!

Comment: @Biggybi no problem :) I sniped you from the comments a bit anyway. Multiple good answers is *usually* a good thing!

Comment: "Beware the man of one book." - Thomas Aquinas

Comment: I upvoted both of your answers, but the `:edit <cfile>` won for the chosen answer. I started using it in parallel with other suggestions, and that's a great addition to my everyday commands.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to open a file under cursor is `gf` (if it's in your `path`).
When the file is a directory, this will open `netrw` (the builtin file explorer) for that directory.

You can also use `:wincmd f` for the same result.

<del>Thus, you can set a mapping to open the file in a vertical split for example:</del>

<del>nnoremap g :vertical wincmd f</del>

This can be done with `<c-w><c-f>`.

A more useful one could be to open the folder in a vertical split on the far-left hand side:

```
nnoremap g<c-f> :Lexplore <cfile><cr>
```

---

From command line, you can use `<c-r><c-a>` to expand the `WORD`.
A `WORD` is a word delimited by white spaces, as opposed to `word` which is delimited by `-`, `_`, and other special characters.

Edit: `<cfile>`, as mentionned by D. Ben Knoble, is way better.

Comment: PS theres even `<C-w>F`!

Comment: And even <c-w><c-f>... that mimics my mapping (or is it the other way around?). I'll give a twist to it to make it original.