# Go to file with gf from :terminal

Tags: vimscript, terminal-buffer, navigation, plugin

I often keep a `:terminal` open on the right of a vertical split, and on the left keep a window open for files:

```
------------------------------
|              |             |
| file buffers | :terminal   |
|              |             |
------------------------------
```

When navigating through the terminal window in normal mode, I'd like to be able to type `gf` when the cursor is positioned over a file path and have it opened in the left window. Is anyone aware of a plugin or script that will allow this sort of thing? Even a snippet to get me started would be helpful. :)

**Bonus:** `git diff` shows file paths prefixed with `a/` and `b/`. It would be great to somehow use `gf` on those as well, with the prefixes ignored:

```
             
diff --git a/dev/pricing_scenario_service/repl_core.clj b/dev/pricing_scenario_service/repl_core.clj
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

If you leave terminal mode (<kbd>Ctrl-\</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>) you can hit <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to duplicate the vertically the tab and hit `gf` to navigate to the file you would like.

Here is a sequence of key that could make the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl-\</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> Leave terminal mode
- <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> Create a vertical split that duplicate the buffer
- <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>Shift-h</kbd> Move the created split to the extreme left
- `gf` Open the corresponding file in the created buffer
- <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> Switch to the window that need to be closed
- `q` Quit the window

In total: <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>Shift-h</kbd>`gf`<kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>`:q`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

You could create a mapping:

```
tnoremap gf <C-\><C-n><C-w>v<C-w>Hgf<C-w>l:q<CR>
nnoremap gf &buftype==#'terminal' ? "<C-w>v<C-w>Hgf<C-w>l:q<CR>" : 'gf'
```

The following answer [Open filename under cursor like gf, but in a new tab (or split)](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3369/23502) gives interesting pointer.

Comment: Brilliant. The `nnoremap` line was messing with `gf` in non-terminal buffers, so I added a test for `&buftype == 'terminal'` in a separate function.

Comment: @apostl3pol Thanks for the feedback. I have integrated your idea into the solution.

Comment: One more thing I noticed today is that the `tnoremap` command is executed whenever I type `gd` at the terminal prompt! I'm just omitting it because I really do only want it in normal mode.

Comment: I suppose you mean `gf` the only way I see is to make the key séquence more rare or to make it dependent of the context.